# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress phpmyadmin 502 error

Tags: kubernetes, phpmyadmin, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to solve quite an annoying problem I encounter when using Kubernetes. When I am trying to reach PHPMyAdmin on my server, it returns an Nginx **502 Bad Gateway** error.

My structure in my cluster is as follows. I use an Nginx ingress LoadBalancer on DigitalOcean to get traffic into my cluster. It then passes my ingress (in the first code block), which splits the traffic across the subdomains.
When traffic goes to the phpmyadmin subdomain, the request is passed to the 'phpmyadmin-service' with service port 8085.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "app1.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app1-service
          servicePort: 80 
  - host: "phpmyadmin.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: phpmyadmin-service
          servicePort: 8085
```

Then, the service receives the request, and passes it to the 'phpmyadmin-deployment' deployment. This is a deployment that runs the phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:fpm docker image.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: phpmyadmin-deployment
  labels:
    app: phpmyadmin
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: phpmyadmin
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: phpmyadmin
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: phpmyadmin
          image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:fpm
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8087
          env:
          - name: PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI
            value: 'phpmyadmin.example.com'
          - name: PMA_HOST
            value: mysql
          - name: PMA_PORT
            value: "3306"
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secrets
                  key: rootpw
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: phpmyadmin
  ports:
  - port: 8085
    targetPort: 8087
```

So something is giving me the 502 Bad Gateway error, and I don't know what it is. Thanks in advance for replying!

Comment: 1.Can you check with `kubectl get pods` if your phpmyadmin deployment is in running state? 2.Can you check with `kubectl logs` if there is anything wrong happening in the phpmyadmin deployment? 3.Is your phpmyadmin image definitely listening on port 8087? I would say it should be 80 unless you changed it.

Comment: 1. Yes it is running. 2. No logs, just says it is ready. 3. Yes it is definitely listening. I changed it to that, 80 doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi @Jurjen, just to clarify, did you change the port in the dockerfile image? If you changed only the containerPort in your deployment then it's not enough.I have tried to reproduce your issue but I couldn't make it work with the `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:fpm`. I would recommend to use `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin` image instead, I have checked and it works on port 80. Could you try with that?